# Get values from enum

Tags: c#, enums

I need find in `enum DaysOfTheWeek` values filtered by `List<int> daysId` and return filtered enum

My enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfTheWeek
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
    AllDays = 127,
}
```

-

```
var allValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfTheWeek));
```

My integer list:

```
List<int> daysId = new List<int> {1,3};
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: When we make `[Flags] enum`, we usually use `0x001`, `0x002`, `0x004`, `0x008`, `0x010`, etc. It's easier to work with (especially when you have lots of options. Also, `AllDays = Sunday | Monday | [...]` would be better, because you wouldn't need to adapt its value, should you want to add or remove days (or change the value of existing ones).

Comment: What is the filter, and what is the expected result? Is it include or exclude filter? It is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
var filtered = daysId.Select(d => (DaysOfTheWeek)d);
```

Comment: While I am entirely unsure, I suspect OP wants the enum values returned in bitmask form, not as an enumerable. But, as I said - entirely unsure.

Comment: var filtered = daysId.Select(d => (DaysOfTheWeek)d); not work currently

Comment: incorrect return, I need return filtered enum by list index [1] and [3]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question. Something like this?

```
var filtered  = daysId.Select(d=>(DaysOfTheWeek)(1<<(d-1))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm over complicating, but check this out:

```
int[] daysId = new int[] { 1, 3,48,127 };

Dictionary<int, List<DaysOfTheWeek>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<DaysOfTheWeek>>();

foreach (int id in daysId)
{
    result[id] = new List<DaysOfTheWeek>();
    BitArray ba = new BitArray(new int[]{id});
    for (int i=0;i<ba.Length;i++)
    {
        if (ba[i])
        {
            result[id].Add((DaysOfTheWeek)(1 << i));
            Console.WriteLine((DaysOfTheWeek)(1 << i));
         }                    
     }
    Console.WriteLine("id-" + id + " > " + (DaysOfTheWeek)id);                
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Check the output and see if it's what you want. You can use the direct conversion to days of week if you want so `(DaysOfTheWeek)id` or you can get each `DaysOfTheWeek` separately. I've done both up above.